# Why doesn't the program terminate when simplify a lemma?

Tags: isabelle

I'm using Isabelle to simplify a lemma using a function`absTransfRule (env N) r`
and the r is a big formula with conjunctions of hundreds of conjuntals. In fact, when the r is small, this process can be terminated. Can someone tell me what does the simplifying procedure do? What causes the stuck? Thanks!

```
lemma abs_NI_Remote_GetX_PutX_Home_ref : 
"[|M <= N;dst <= M|] 
==> absTransfRule (env N) M (NI_Remote_GetX_PutX_Home_ref N dst) = 
NI_Remote_GetX_PutX_Home_ref M dst"             
"[|M <= N;dst > M|] 
==> absTransfRule (env N) M (NI_Remote_GetX_PutX_Home_ref N dst) = 
ABS_NI_Remote_GetX_PutX_Home M"
unfolding NI_Remote_GetX_PutX_Home_ref_def 
NI_Remote_GetX_PutX_Home_ref_def ABS_NI_Remote_GetX_PutX_Home_def  apply(auto simp 
add: Let_def )   
done
```

---

This is an additional description of the problem
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdaNr.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/syfOZ.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1QKO.png

Comment: Did you try `supply [[simp_trace_new]]` to trace what the simplifier is doing?